# Consulta Transação manualmente laravel pagseguro

Tags: php, laravel

Olá, estou Tentando fazer uma consulta de Transação manualmente seguindo o modelo passado pelo autor do componente michaeldouglas/laravel-pagseguro, mas quando tento retorna o seguinte erro:

```
Non-static method laravel\pagseguro\Facades\PagSeguro::transaction() should not be called statically
```

Link do repositório:

```
https://github.com/michaeldouglas/laravel-pagseguro
```

Segue meu código de consulta:

```
 foreach($atualizar as $pagamento){
        $transaction = PagSeguro::transaction()->get($pagamento->codigo, $credentials);
        $information = $transaction->getInformation();
    }
```

Quem puder ajudar fico imensamente grato!

******************Não funcionou utilizando o método do repositorio*********************

FIz uma consulta utilizando o seguinte código

```
    $email = env('PAGSEGURO_EMAIL');
    $token = env('PAGSEGURO_TOKEN');

    $client = new Client;
    $atualizar = Pagamento::whereIn('status',[Pagamento::STATUS_AGUARDANDO_PAGAMENTO,Pagamento::STATUS_ANALISE,Pagamento::STATUS_PAGA])->get()->first();
    return $response = $client->request('GET', 'https://ws.sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/transactions', [
        'query' => [
            'reference'   => $atualizar->codigo,
            'email' => $email, 
            'token' => $token,
        ]
    ]);
```

a consulta funcionou mas não me retorna dados: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

mas a transação existe na sandbox:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

entretanto esse código que apresenta na sandbox é diferente do código que eu capturei quando criei o pagamento tanto que está diferendo do código do meu banco de dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já fiz a busca tanto pelo código do meu banco quanto pelo gerado na sandbox   e não consegui retorno.

Answer (score 1):

Amigo,

Olhei o [repositório que você mencionou](https://github.com/michaeldouglas/laravel-pagseguro), existem 2 classes com mesmo nome chamada de "PagSeguro":

```
laravel\pagseguro\Platform\Laravel5\Pagseguro
laravel\pagseguro\Facades\Pagseguro
```

E ainda tem uma "terceira" que é a facade que você registra como alias em `config.app`:

```
'aliases' => [
    ...
    'PagSeguro' => laravel\pagseguro\Platform\Laravel5\PagSeguro::class,
    ...

]
```

Você pode utilizar tanto a do `config.app` como a `laravel\pagseguro\Platform\Laravel5\PagSeguro`

```
\\ utilizando o Alias registrado no config.app
use Pagseguro;

\\ou diretamente a Facade
\\use laravel\pagseguro\Platform\Laravel5\PagSeguro;

...
foreach($atualizar as $pagamento){
    $transaction = PagSeguro::transaction()->get($pagamento->codigo, $credentials);
    $information = $transaction->getInformation();
}
...
```

Acredito que você deve ter registrado errado o alias no config.appp ou referenciado a classe errada ali no cabeçalho do seu script.

É importante que você registre corretamente o service provider também em `config.app`:

```
'providers' => [
    ...
    laravel\pagseguro\Platform\Laravel5\ServiceProvider::class,
    ...
]
```

Se você utilizar diretamente a classe `laravel\pagseguro\Facades\PagSeguro` esta realmente não possui nenhum método estático ou método mágico para resolver.

```
<?php
namespace laravel\pagseguro\Facades;
/**
 * PagSeguro Facade
 * @author  Isaque de Souza <isaquesb@gmail.com>
 */
class PagSeguro
{
    /**
     * @return Checkout
     */
    public function checkout()
    {
        return new Checkout();
    }
    /**
     * @return Plan
     */
    public function plan()
    {
        return new Plan();
    }
    /**
     * @return Credentials
     */
    public function credentials()
    {
        return new Credentials();
    }
    /**
     * @return Item
     */
    public function item()
    {
        return new Item();
    }
    /**
     * @return Transaction
     */
    public function transaction()
    {
        return new Transaction();
    }
}
```

Acredito que aqui você já deve ter resolvido o problema. Daqui para baixo é apenas uma explicação de como funcionam as Facades para você saber qual classe utilizar e porquê.

---

## Como funciona uma Facade

É importante entender a mecânica, o funcionamento de [Facades no Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/facades). Vou tomar o próprio PagSeguro como exemplo.

1o é registrado um [service provider](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/providers) no  `config.app`.

```
'providers' => [
    ...
    laravel\pagseguro\Platform\Laravel5\ServiceProvider::class,
    ...
]
```

### O que o service provider faz?

Vamos ver o trecho do código:

```
/**
 * Register the service provider.
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('pagseguro', function () {
        $platform = new Laravel5();
        Config::usePlatform($platform);
        $facade = new PagSeguroFacade();
        return $facade;
    });
}
/**
 * Get the services provided by the provider.
 * @return array
 */
public function provides()
{
    return ['pagseguro'];
}
```

Este trecho de código do service provider está basicamente registrando um alias chamado "pagseguro" e resolvendo um objeto concreto "laravel\pagseguro\Facades\PagSeguro".

Então ao chamar `resolve('pagseguro')` ou `app('pagsegoro)` ou `$this->app->make('pageguro')` ou ainda `$this->app['pagseguro']`em alguns pontos do laravel, o Container do laravel irá retornar o objeto concreto registrado ali em cima.

2o é registrado o Facade também no `app.config`

```
'aliases' => [
    ...
    'PagSeguro' => laravel\pagseguro\Platform\Laravel5\PagSeguro::class,
    ...

]
```

### O que esse Facade faz?

Vamos ver o trecho do código:

```
namespace laravel\pagseguro\Platform\Laravel5;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;
/**
 * PagSeguro Laravel Facade
 * @author  Michael Douglas <michaeldouglas010790@gmail.com>
 */
class PagSeguro extends Facade
{
    /**
     * Get the registered name of the component.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'pagseguro';
    }
}
```

Basicamente vai retornar a string "pagseguro" que é o alias para o objeto concreto.

Esta classe extenso o `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade`

Por último vamos ver como esta funciona:

```
/**
 * Handle dynamic, static calls to the object.
 *
 * @param  string  $method
 * @param  array   $args
 * @return mixed
 *
 * @throws \RuntimeException
 */
public static function __callStatic($method, $args)
{
    $instance = static::getFacadeRoot();

    if (! $instance) {
        throw new RuntimeException('A facade root has not been set.');
    }

    return $instance->$method(...$args);
}
```

O [método mágico](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.callstatic) `__callStatic` irá resolver o objeto concreto e chamar o método deste objeto que você chamou estaticamente.

Em termos práticos:

```
laravel\pagseguro\Platform\Laravel5\PagSeguro::transaction()

1-O facade resolve o objeto concreto (laravel\pagseguro\Facades\Pagseguro) devidamente configurado no service provider;
2-Chama o método "transaction" do objeto concreto
```

A propósito a nomeclatura de classes do [repositório](https://github.com/michaeldouglas/laravel-pagseguro) em questão ficou um pouco confusa, já que existem 2 classes facade "PagSeguro", sendo que uma é realmente uma Facade do Laravel, e outra é um serviço ou container de serviços (apesar do namesapace "Facade"). Esta nomeclatura confusa deve ter originado seu erro.

Espero ter ajudado e esclarecido.

Abraços.

Comment: não consegui mas estou consultando agora via curl e não está dando retorno

Comment: se puder me ajudar actualizei a pergunta, se tiver como me passar seu contato fica ate mais fácil para te perguntar melhor kkk

Answer (score 1):

Tulio,

Ao que parece o problema esta sendo a informação em vez da implementação certo?

Você não teve resultado mesmo com o código da transação que foi retornado ao criar a mesma?

Tenta usar essa API no postman com o código de 32 digitos que vc recebeu:
https://dev.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v1.0/reference#consulta-dos-detalhes-da-transa%C3%A7%C3%A3o

Lembrando que código de referência não é código de transação.

Código de referência é SEU e você passa pra eles.

Código de transação é DELES e eles passam pra vc no retorno da criação da transação.

Comment: Você não teve resultado mesmo com o código da transação que foi retornado ao criar a mesma? : não obtive nenhum resultado, fala que o código é invalido! Tenta usar essa API no postman com o código de 32 digitos que vc recebeu. : tentei e continua dando a mesma coisa!!! se tu puder me passar seu contato para te mostrar o código... @isaque-souza

Comment: @TulioVieira, conseguiu resolver o problema? Se não conseguiu pela API via postman é problema entre o cadastro e o sandbox no PagSeguro. Novas transações resultam no mesmo problema? Se quiser pode entrar em contato no isaquesb@gmail.com
Vlw!

Comment: sim consegui resolver o problema adicionei o referece code e pesquisei por ele e deu tudo certo @Isaque Souza